# Is there a way to access public facebook information, like photo, status update for a user without them using an app I wrote?

Tags: javascript, facebook, perl, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm new to coding for Facebook, but I was wondering if there is a way to access public information for users listed in the public directory without writing an application that they use? I code mostly in perl.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "public directory" ?

You can use the graph.facebook.com sub domain to access the public infos in REST.
http://graph.facebook.com/userID or PageID

Example : http://graph.facebook.com/nike

Comment: Thanks Alex, I appreciate the polite and helpful response. Thats exactly what I was after.